# How to increase UIImage pixels to post to Instagram

Tags: ios, uiimage, instagram, uigraphicscontext, cgsize

I have captured an image on an app I am creating using the code below. It captures and stores the image perfectly and I can post it to Facebook & Twitter perfectly fine. However, it wont let me post it to Instagram because the image size isn't at least 612px x 612px. Is there any way I can increase the pixel size of my image? It would only need a slight increase as it is already at 568px x 570px. Any advise would be great! Thanks!

Code to get capture image:

```
CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0.0);
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 ); //you can use PNG too

UIImage * imagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:theImageData]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return imagePNG;
```

Code to post to Instagram:

```
//Instagram Image
if (_testImage.image.size.width < 612 || _testImage.image.size.height <612) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Information" message:@"The image you are trying to post to Instagram is too small. Image must be at least 612px x 612px" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    NSLog(@"image size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(_testImage.image.size));
    [alert show];
}else{
    NSString* imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.igo", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_testImage.image, 0.2) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"image size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(_testImage.image.size));
    _docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
    _docController.delegate=self;
    _docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    [_docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale it, but this will make the quality of your images worse.

Scale method:

```
- (UIImage*)scaleImage:(UIImage*)image withScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width*scale, image.size.height*scale);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has answered my question. You are right, it has made my image worse, so I have changed my approach. This is the correct answer to my question though so thanks again!